# NGINX Proxy: No cargan los recursos

Tags: linux, http, nginx, https, proxy

Hola que tal soy un poco nuevo en NGINX y me surge el siguiente problema

Tengo un proxy limpio, recién instalado, hice distintas pruebas y ningún problema pero al momento de querer entrar a un subdominio con el proxy_pass en el proxy y entrar a ese subdominio solo con la dirección IP puedo entrar a la pagina pero no me cargan los recursos (CSS, imagenes, etc).

Esta es mi configuración

```
    server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       location / {
        proxy_pass https://172.16.0.2/test;
       }
}
```

También probé con esto pero no hubo caso

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

location /test/ {
    rewrite ^/test(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass  https://172.16.0.2/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect    off;
}
}
```

Si en location agrego el /test/ en el primer ejemplo funciona, pero la idea es querer entrar solo con la IP sin tener que agregar algo mas.

¿Alguna idea de que podría ser?